# ValueError: Expected input data to be non-empty

Tags: python, deep-learning, lstm, training-data

This is my code:

```
x_test = []
y_test = dataset[training_data_len:, :]
for i in range (60,len(test_data)):
    x_test.append(test_data[i - 60 :i, 0])


x_test = np.array(x_test)

x_test = np.reshape(x_test , (x_test.shape[0] ,x_test.shape[1],1))
```

when I wrote this line:

```
predictions = model.predict(x_test)
predictions = scaler.inverse_transform(predictions)
```

I got this Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[26], line 1
----> 1 predictions = model.predict(x_test)
      2 predictions = scaler.inverse_transform(predictions)

File c:\Users\hemic\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

File c:\Users\hemic\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\data_adapter.py:1319, in DataHandler.__init__(self, x, y, sample_weight, batch_size, steps_per_epoch, initial_epoch, epochs, shuffle, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, model, steps_per_execution, distribute, pss_evaluation_shards)
   1314 self._configure_dataset_and_inferred_steps(
   1315     strategy, x, steps_per_epoch, class_weight, distribute
   1316 )
   1318 if self._inferred_steps == 0:
-> 1319     raise ValueError("Expected input data to be non-empty.")
```

ValueError: Expected input data to be non-empty.

How would I go about fixing this error?

Comment: The error you are getting suggests the input data is empty. Have you tried working backwards, to figure out where x_test is becoming empty? Try printing out an excerpt of x_test at various breakpoints in your code. Debugging in this way will help you narrow down on what is causing the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is `test_data` defined?

Is its length more than 60?

If not, the code does not enter the loop and `x_test` remains empty.

Comment: training_data_len = math.ceil(len(dataset) * .8)

Comment: test_data = scaled_data [training_data_len - 60, :]

Comment: So, scaled_data[training_data_len_60,:] picks up only one sample, and len(test_data) becomes 1 and the code does not enter the loop because the range is (60, 1)

Comment: please can you tell me where I change.

Comment: I think yo want to select the samples from training_data_len - 60 to the end in the scaled data. So, change it to this: test_data=scaled_data[training_data_len-60:, :] (mind the colon after 60.)

Comment: @leone please do **not** post code or data in the comments; **edit & update** your post instead.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the error indicates that your `x_test` is empty when you're trying to make predictions with your model.

- Before the loop, check that `test_data` is defined (print out the first few rows to check)
- Make sure that your `test_data` includes elements between `60` and `len(test_data)
- Print out `x_test` after your loop to ensure it's not empty

The above should help in figuring out where the error is stemming from.

Comment: x_test value is 0.16871092 so it's less than 1

Comment: I mean Test_data

Answer (score 0):

If you look at here:

```py
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[26], line 1
----> 1 predictions = model.predict(x_test)
      2 predictions = scaler.inverse_transform(predictions)
```

You see that x_test is empty and not appending anything to itself.

**1.Loop Range:**
First, check that test_data is greater than 1

**2.Empty Test Data:**
Be sure that test_data is not empty.

Comment: Test_data value is 0.16871092